# how to set multiple headers in angularjs $httpProvides?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-headers

I have to add two headers in my $http.post

one is 'Content-Type' and the other is 'token'

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'    //Content-Type to fix ' Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['token'] = sessionStorage['token']
```

and the headers is added!

```
post: {Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Token: "a2186fd57ad0fb3daaed28cc6920491d"}
```

[image]

but it seems that two headers in $httpProvider doesn't matter.

because the safari is still Access-Control-Allow-Origin

[image]

```
 Origin http://localhost:8099 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

when I just use one headers, it works.

so, how can I config two headers in $httpProvider?

Comment: From the error image that you have provided, it seems like issue is the content is not accessible due to cross origin request. What platform you are using for server application ? You have to enable CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) in server side.